# XPATH or XSL to match two node-sets using custom comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**EDIT:** I also have access to [ESXLT](http://www.exslt.org/) functions.

I have two node sets of string tokens. One set contains values like these:

```
/Geography/North America/California/San Francisco
/Geography/Asia/Japan/Tokyo/Shinjuku
```

The other set contains values like these:

```
/Geography/North America/
/Geography/Asia/Japan/
```

My goal is to find a "match" between the two. A match is made when any string in set 1 begins with a string in set 2. For example, a match would be made between **/Geography/North America/California/San Francisco** and **/Geography/North America/** because a string from set 1 begins with a string from set 2.

I can compare strings using wildcards by using a third-party extension. I can also use a regular expression all within an Xpath.

My problem is how do I structure the Xpath to select using a function between all nodes of both sets? XSL is also a viable option.

This XPATH:

```
count($set1[.=$set2])
```

Would yield the count of intersection between set1 and set2, but it's a 1-to-1 comparison. Is it possible to use some other means of comparing the nodes?

EDIT: I did get this working, but I am cheating by using some of the other third-party extensions to get the same result. I am still interested in other methods to get this done.

Comment: So, in your above example, you want the count of matching items? So the above should return 2?

Comment: Yes, with my given example the count should be two.

Comment: Is a single XPath expression the only option?  Would XSLT be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, XSLT is also a viable option. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Zack, There is a simple and pure XSLT 1.0 solution (no extensions needed) for finding the count of matches. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<xsl:variable name="matches" select="$set1[starts-with(., $set2)]"/>
```

will set `$matches` to a node-set containing every node in `$set1` whose text value starts with the text value of a node in $set2.  That's what you're looking for, right?

**Edit:**

Well, I'm just wrong about this.  Here's why.

`starts-with` expects its two arguments to both be strings.  If they're not, it will convert them to strings before evaluating the function.

If you give it a node-set as one of its arguments, it uses the string value of the node-set, which is the text value of the first node in the set.  So in the above, `$set2` never gets searched; only the first node in the list ever gets examined, and so the predicate will only find nodes in `$set1` that start with the value of the first node in `$set2`.

I was misled because this pattern (which I've been using a lot in the last few days) *does* work:

```
<xsl:variable name="hits" select="$set1[. = $set2]"/>
```

But that predicate is using an comparison between node-sets, not between text values.

The ideal way to do this would be by nesting predicates.  That is, "I want to find every node in `$set1` for which there's a node in `$set2` whose value starts with..." and here's where XPath breaks down.  Starts with what?  What you'd like to write is something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="matches" select="$set1[$set2[starts-with(?, .)]]"/>
```

only there's no expression you can write for the `?` that will return the node currently being tested by the outer predicate.  (Unless I'm missing something blindingly obvious.)

To get what you want, you have to test each node individually:

```
<xsl:variable name="matches">
  <xsl:for-each select="$set1">
    <xsl:if test="$set2[starts-with(current(), .)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

That's not a very satisfying solution because it evaluates to a result tree fragment, not a node-set.  You'll have to use an extension function (like `msxsl:node-set`) to convert the RTF to a node-set if you want to use the variable in an XPath expression.

Comment: Yes! What a simple and elegant solution. This is just what I needed -- thanks very much!

Comment: I did indeed speak too soon as ChuckB's post shows. Luckily for me, the third-party extensions I'm using allow me to solve this problem in another way.

Comment: Robert, There is a simple and pure XSLT 1.0 solution (no extensions needed) for finding the count of matches. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a simple and pure XSLT 1.0 solution (no extensions needed) for finding the count of matches**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vStars">
            <xsl:for-each select="*/regions/*">
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/cities/*[starts-with(.,current())]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'*'"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($vStars)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <cities>
        <city>/Geography/North America/California/San Francisco</city>
        <city>/Geography/Asia/Japan/Tokyo/Shinjuku</city>
    </cities>
    <regions>
        <region>/Geography/North America/</region>
        <region>/Geography/Asia/Japan/</region>
    </regions>
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

***2***

**Do note** that one character (an asterisk) is produced for every match found and all these asterisks form the content of the `$vStars` variable. We then simply output its `string-length()`.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's last `xsl:variable` is good for getting a result tree fragment containing the matching text values, but unless (as he suggests) you use EXSLT or MS extensions to XSLT 1.0 to convert the RTF to a node set, you can't get a count of the matching text nodes.

Here is the XSLT stylesheet I mentioned in my prior response that recurs over the sample input document I gave to give a count of text nodes in set 1 for which a node in set 2 matches part or all of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="count-matches">
      <xsl:with-param name="set1-node" select="sets/set[1]/text[1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="set2-node" select="sets/set[2]/text[1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="total-count" select="0"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="count-matches">
    <xsl:param name="set1-node"/>
    <xsl:param name="set2-node"/>
    <xsl:param name="total-count" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="this-count">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($set1-node, $set2-node)">
          <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$set2-node/following-sibling::text">
        <xsl:call-template name="count-matches">
          <xsl:with-param name="set1-node"
                          select="$set1-node"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="set2-node"
                          select="$set2-node/following-sibling::text[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="total-count"
                          select="$total-count + $this-count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$set1-node/following-sibling::text">
        <xsl:call-template name="count-matches">
          <xsl:with-param name="set1-node"
                          select="$set1-node/following-sibling::text[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="set2-node"
                          select="$set2-node/preceding-sibling::text[last()]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="total-count"
                          select="$total-count + $this-count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total-count + $this-count"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not particularly concise, but because XSLT does not let programmers assign new values to already-defined variables, recursion is often necessary.  I don't see a way in XSLT 1.0 to get a count of the sort requested by Zack using `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Chuck, There is a simple and pure XSLT 1.0 solution (no extensions needed) for finding the count of matches. See my answer

Answer (score -1):

I guess I couldn't make the XPath above work.  I started with the following XML doc to initialize the two nodesets:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sets>
  <set>
    <text>/Geography/North America/California/San Francisco</text>
    <text>/Geography/Asia/Japan/Tokyo/Shinjuku</text>
  </set>
  <set>
    <text>/Geography/North America/</text>
    <text>/Geography/Asia/Japan/</text>
  </set>
</sets>
```

I think this stylesheet ought to implement Robert's solution, but I only get a count of '1':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="set1" select="sets/set[1]/text/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="set2" select="sets/set[2]/text/text()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($set1[starts-with(., $set2)])"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did write a stylesheet that uses a recursive template and does produce the correct count of '2' with the given input doc, but it's far less elegant than Robert's answer.  If only I could get the XPath to work--always wanting to learn.