# xpath/xslt equal check for multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

For example I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TemporaryRoot>
    <ProcessPurchaseOrder>
        <DocumentReference>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688401</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688404</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688405</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
    </ProcessPurchaseOrder>
    <DbResponse>
        <ResultSet>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688401</Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688404</Cell>
            </Row>
        </ResultSet>
    </DbResponse>
</TemporaryRoot>
```

How to write xpath or xslt code to check if `DbResponse/ResultSet/Row/Cell[@name="WEANR"]` contain all values from `AlternateDocumentID/ID`'s

in this example result is false, because `DbResponse/ResultSet/Row/Cell[@name="WEANR"]` doesn't have `0171688405` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this single XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
not(/*/ProcessPurchaseOrder
                /*/*/ID[not(. = /*/DbResponse/*/*/Cell[@name='WEANR'])])
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "not(/*/ProcessPurchaseOrder
                /*/*/ID[not(. = /*/DbResponse/*/*/Cell[@name='WEANR'])])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied against the provided XML document:**

```
<TemporaryRoot>
    <ProcessPurchaseOrder>
        <DocumentReference>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688401</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688404</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688405</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
    </ProcessPurchaseOrder>
    <DbResponse>
        <ResultSet>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688401</Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688404</Cell>
            </Row>
        </ResultSet>
    </DbResponse>
</TemporaryRoot>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result is copied to the output:**

```
false
```

**When we change the document to this:**

```
<TemporaryRoot>
    <ProcessPurchaseOrder>
        <DocumentReference>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688401</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
            <AlternateDocumentID>
                <ID>0171688404</ID>
            </AlternateDocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
    </ProcessPurchaseOrder>
    <DbResponse>
        <ResultSet>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688401</Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">0171688404</Cell>
            </Row>
        </ResultSet>
    </DbResponse>
</TemporaryRoot>
```

**the transformation applied on this document again produces the correct result:**

```
true
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Double-Negation Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**.

Comment: @VextoR, In this answer I put a link to the double - negation law. So, all items in a collection have a property X, iff there isn't an item that doesn't have this property X. Now, just replace in the previous sentence "collection" with `/*/ProcessPurchaseOrder/*/*/ID` and "property X" with `= /*/DbResponse/*/*/Cell[@name='WEANR']`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than Dimitre's use of `not(X[not(. = Y)])`, which is a little difficult to understand for those without either mathematical training or an intuitive grasp of symbolic logic, you could use the XPath 2.0 construct

```
every $x in X satisfies (some $y in Y satisfies $x eq $y)
```

specifically

```
every $id in //ID satisfies (some $cell in //Cell satisfies $id eq $cell)
```

You could also mix the explicit quantification of this example with the implicit quantification of the "=" operator by writing

```
every $id in //ID satisfies ($id = //Cell)
```

which would probably be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

As an XPath solution, you could check for all nodes in `Row/Cell` that match the `AlternateDocumentID/ID` nodes, then compare it to the total nodes:

```
count(//DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell/@name='WEANR' and  //AlternateDocumentID/ID/text() = Cell/text()]) = count(//AlternateDocumentID/ID)
```

For an XSLT solution, [here's a good example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269989/xpath-or-xsl-to-match-two-node-sets-using-custom-comparison) for how to do that.