# XSL:template & Combination of two match conditions to select outer node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following (part of a) XML file:

```
<span deltaxml:deltaV2="A!=B">
    <deltaxml:attributes deltaxml:deltaV2="A!=B">
      <dxa:class deltaxml:deltaV2="A!=B">
        <deltaxml:attributeValue deltaxml:deltaV2="B">LoF</deltaxml:attributeValue>
      </dxa:class>
    </deltaxml:attributes>
    Some Text
</span>
```

... I want / need to match those `<span>` nodes in a `<xsl:template match="..">` statement that target specifically spans with

- The span itself having a *deltaxml:deltaV2* attribute with a '*A!=B*' value and also
- the exact *deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/deltaxml:attributeValue* child structure with this inner-most *deltaxml:attributeValue* node having that *deltaxml:deltaV2* attribute set to a '*B*' value and also containing '*LoF*' as its value / text

Basically I need to match this exact condition shown above to later select / use the 'Some Text' part.. but that's the easy thing to do once I matched the `<span>` node(s) in the input xml.. but so far I've been scratching my head and failed to select the node(s).

Maybe anyone is fluent in slightly more complex match statements and knows which one would be the correct one here. Thanks!

Comment: So where are you stuck? Try an XPath tutorial on how to select an attribute, then look at predicates for your value comparisons. The `deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/deltaxml:attributeValue` can be written exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a big predicate expression `and`'ing and counting the attributes. The nodes do not have to be matched directly because attributes without elements cannot exist. However, the elements and attributes are counted to ensure that there are no more nor less elements/attributes in the `span`/element, respectively. The text nodes are not handled, merely the existence of `Some Text` is checked.

So the following complex expression does match *exactly* the element/attribute tree structure you described:

```
<xsl:template match="span[
  @deltaxml:deltaV2='A!=B' and 
  count(descendant::*)=3 and
  deltaxml:attributes/@deltaxml:deltaV2 and
  count(deltaxml:attributes/@*)=1 and
  deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/@deltaxml:deltaV2 and
  count(deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/@*)=1 and 
  deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/deltaxml:attributeValue/@deltaxml:deltaV2='B' and
  count(deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/deltaxml:attributeValue/@*)=1 and 
  deltaxml:attributes/dxa:class/deltaxml:attributeValue/text()='LoF' and
  normalize-space(text()[2])='Some Text']">
  MATCH!
</xsl:template>
```

---

Unfortunately comparing two *Resulting Tree Fragments* in variables containing the sub-trees does not work because there is no *compare-op* for it ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/269989/1305969)).